# New to Ubuntu - Realtek Ethernet drivers

Tags: drivers, ethernet, realtek

I have recently dual boot'd my new rig for my data science stuff. So yea...I'm purely new here Ubuntu (Tho. I hear'd Linux/Ubuntu already lol). I'm currently running an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with a kernel ver. of 5.4.0-42-generic. As of the moment, I'm running with an ethernet cable and ofc problems with regards to installing the ethernet drivers from Realtek.

Firstly, I checked the network description which indicates a network unclaimed...

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   version: 04
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fc500000-fc50ffff memory:fc510000-fc513fff
```

As I scoured in previous forums, you can easily download the drivers from this -> [Realtek](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software). I DID! the steps from the README file only to hit a road block yet again.

By running the autorun.sh file from the command line, it just says

```
$ sudo ./autorun.sh
Check old driver and unload it.
Build the module and install
./autorun.sh: 31: make: not found
```

I give it a shot find out my ethernet card and it says

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:8125] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [1043:87d7]
    Kernel modules: r8169
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:2484] (rev a1)
```

I'm literally needing some help or someone who can thoroughly guide me on how to 'install' the ethernet drivers on this one. :C

Regards,

astro_cgha

Comment: The program called `make`, needed to compile software from source, is missing on your system. The question is, how do you install the package if your network isn't working? One option is to download the package on a different machine: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/make-dfsg/make_4.2.1-1.2_amd64.deb , copy it to your Ubuntu machine and install with: `sudo dpkg -i make_4.2.1-1.2_amd64.deb`

Comment: Hello. I apologize for the late response. so right after I install that package, I can redo the 'methodology' that I did from the autorun.sh?

Comment: Yes, you can repeat the process. Unless it turns out that something more is missing...

Comment: Ok thnx. I'll be back as soon as I get somethin' on that. c:

Comment: hello. So it says now; Check old driver and unload it.
Build the module and install
make[2]: gcc: Command not found
arch/x86/Makefile:147: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
make[2]: gcc: Command not found
/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /home/astro_cgha/Downloads/r8125-9.004.01/src/r8125_n.o] Error 127
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1731: /home/astro_cgha/Downloads/r8125-9.004.01/src] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:159: modules] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:41: modules] Error 2

Comment: So the whole `build-essential` suite is missing on your system. There will be a few more packages that you'll need to install using the metod described above. Besides `make`, these are: `libc6-dev`, `gcc`, `g++` and `dpkg-dev`. In the next comment, I will prepare a list of URLs to download for you.

Comment: It seems that mentioned packages have their own dependencies, so there will be even more to install. Is it possible to connect your machine to the network via some other interface, for example wifi or an external USB Ethernet adapter? Then it will be possible to install everything automatically.

Comment: hello. Yes. I may try to do that via usb tethering.

Comment: So if you are able to establish the network connection, type the following command: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`. That should install everything you need to build software.

Comment: Ok so I was able to get a wired connection. As soon as i did, I  immediately get a message of a software updater (I think its... Fine lol?)... However, when i tried to do the ''sudo apt-get install build-essential'', it says E: could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 5239 (aptd) N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a soln and may break your system. E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?

Comment: You cannot have two programs install/update software at once. So either postpone the software update or let it complete, and then run `apt-get install`.

Comment: Oh. Ahahahhaha. Ok. Let me get this update done 

Comment: I was able to successfully install the 'build-essentials'... So I can now do the previous process am I right?

Comment: Yes, I think it should work now. :)

Comment: Yep. Its working right now. :) Thank you very much for the extensive help 

Comment: Hello. Do you have perhaps an email where I can contact you incase of network stuff emergency? Apparently, the wired ethernet connection got lost again. I may jump/hop instead into 20.10 ubuntu... :c

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119121/discussion-between-cgha-and-raj).